# Disable submit button in Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm writing a form and have a multi-select with certain responses (age range); for ranges below a specified value, we redirect users to a page with information on why we don't accept that range currently, etc.

The problem is that the form navigation appears on this page, so they can hit Back (no problem) and Submit (problem).

We don't want users submitting if they wind up on this error-catch page, but I haven't seen any way of disabling or hiding the submit button.

Even checking Google scripts, it doesn't seem like this is possible? Does anyone know if there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SUBMIT button either appears on the last page, or on pages where the setting is set to:  Submit Form

You probably have the error page as the last page, and the next to last page set to Submit Form.

There is no way to disable the submit button.  Put the error page BEFORE the last page.  Make the page that is right before the error page skip over the error page and navigate to the last page (Submit Page).  On the last page have only one question like: Are you done? "Yes" "No"  This way, the user will never see the submit button until they get to that last page.  On the Error page, set the page navigation to go to something like back to the first page.  If the user clicks BACK on the SUBMIT page, it will skip over the error page and go to the page before it.  Of course, the user could navigate back, and change the answer, and get to the SUBMIT page.  But then they'd be lying about their age.

Comment: This is pretty close; I reordered the pages, and changed the error page to go back to the first page, making the "continue" button identical to the back button, which is good enough for my purposes. The correct path skips over that page entirely, which is right. Marked as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Google form by accessing Responses tab and unchecking the option Acception responses.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this restrict Data in Google Sheets with Data Validationso it will show a pop up message based on DATA
https://www.howtogeek.com/428919/how-to-restrict-data-input-in-google-sheets-with-data-validation/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)